# add_rewrite_rule on multisite doesn't work

Tags: multisite, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I define a rewrite rule on an init hook like:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'foobar/(abc|def|ghi)/(.+)(/(\d.+))', 'index.php?my_action=$matches[1]&my_name=$matches[2]&my_version=$matches[4]', 'top');
```

This works with following URL on a single WP installation:

```
http://example.com/foobar/def/whatever/1.2
```

However it doesn't on a multisite installation.

It [seems there's problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144366/add-rewrite-rule-not-registering-on-multisite#144377) with rewrite rules on multisite an there's ticket [#19896](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19896) which describes a similar problem on "non WP rules"

I have no idea what I should add to the `.htaccess` file and I prefer a "proper" solution.

**EDIT:**

I have forget something important:

I'm using [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) to use different domains and while the network is on `network.example.com` the site I use `add_rewrite_rule` is sub.example.com

Comment: Since you rewrite to `index.php` it should work. Did you flush your rules?

Comment: about 10 times ;)

Comment: you don't have a non-wp rule, because you're pointing it to index.php. are you certain this works on a single installation? your query string doesn't contain any native query vars, so it can't generate a main query and will 404, the behavior you see is completely expected.

Comment: Yes, that ticket definitely does not apply to you. Rewrite rules that start with index.php are WP rules and don't modify the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is not with `add_rewrite_rule` rather with the `.htaccess`file for the multi site.

One of the test addresses was

```
http://example.com/foobar/def/whatever.php
```

Here's a part of the htaccess which causes the result (Line 2)

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If I comment this line out it works as expected but it may break other thing. So you have to add your own rule **above** the latest block:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?foobar/(abc|def|ghi)/(.+)(/(\d.+))$ index.php?my_action=$2&my_name=$3&my_version=$5 [R=301,L]
```